# error concatenating string in php

Tags: php, string, string-concatenation

if i run the code below i see only the word test and not categories within <> how can this be solved

```
$xmlstring='test';
$xmlstring= $xmlstring . ' <categories> ';
$xmlstring='test';
echo $xmlstring;
```

also tested code below

```
$xmlstring='test';
$xmlstring=$xmlstring . '&lt; categories &gt;';
$xmlstring='test';
echo $xmlstring;
```

also tested this

```
$xmlstring='test';
$xmlstring=$xmlstring . htmlspecialchars('<categories>');
$xmlstring='test';
echo $xmlstring;
```

tnx a lot

Comment: The 2nd statement ($xmlstring='test';) is NOT concatenating the string - use .=

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
$xmlstring='test';
$xmlstring.=htmlspecialchars('<categories>');
$xmlstring.='test';
echo $xmlstring;
```

OR this

```
$xmlstring = 'test';
$xmlstring = $xmlstring . htmlspecialchars('<categories>');
$xmlstring = $xmlstring . 'test';
echo $xmlstring;
```